# What is trimming the fuel tank?

Tags: fuel-tanks, trim

In a recent [news article](http://aviationweek.com/defense/software-cut-fuel-supply-stricken-a400m) on an Airbus A400M crash, it has the following line:

> Sources have told Aviation Week that aircraft MSN23, destined for Turkey, featured new software that would trim the fuel tanks, allowing the aircraft to fly certain military maneuvers.

I understand what [trimming](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/164/what-does-the-term-trimming-most-commonly-mean-in-aviation) is, but what does it mean to **trim the fuel tanks**?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just like normal trimming. However trim the fuel tank use **aft fuel tank** to achieve the trimming effect. Fuel is pumped between main tank and aft tank to shift CG around to a desire position during flight.

Fuel tank trimming has additional benefit of keeping the airplane in "clean" configuration, creating less drag compare to normal trimming.

Comment: What is "clean" configuration of an airplane?

Comment: @iamcreasy: Gears and flaps up; read "clean" as "aerodynamically clean".

Comment: In this context, clean refers NOT to gear/flaps, but to the absence of drag due to trim tabs or drag-generating control forces keeping the aircraft level.  In concept, if the tail has to produce lift down because the aircraft is nose-heavy, that's less efficient than if it didn't have to.